# BSD licenses: What to do with "year" and "copyright holder"?

Tags: license-notice, bsd

We develop a desktop application that uses some libraries with BSD-license.

BSD licenses got this line: Copyright (c) "year", "copyright holder".

Shall one leave it this way or do I have to fill the "year" and "copyright holder" (in case my program uses a library with a BSD license)?

Answer (score 1):

You have a copyright interest in any work to which you contribute copyrightable content.  It is best to indicate this by **adding** to the lines, so that it goes from

```
(c) 2015, Fred Yoyodyne
```

to

```
(c) 2015, Fred Yoyodyne
(c) 2018, Runtime Error
```

assuming that is your real name.  I have no understanding of the copyright implications of a pseudonymous declaration, but I doubt it will help make things simpler.

Note that, whatever the answer to your question, it remains a question of *asserting* copyright.  That is unrelated to the question of how you *license that interest out*, so the answer isn't different for BSD, GPL, and so on.